# How can one construct the pair of three dimensional representations of $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ explicitly?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, characters

The group $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)\cong GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$ has a pair of (complex) three dimensional representations, and I am wondering if anyone knows an explicit construction of these. To clarify what I mean by explicit, we can recognise the $6$ and $7$ irreducible dimensional representations being associated to the $2$-transitive actions on the fano plane and projective line over $\mathbb{F}_7$ respectively, and the $8$ dimensional representation is induced from a nontrivial linear rep of the index $8$ subgroup $C_7\rtimes C_3$. Its also the Steinberg representation, which I am not really familiar with, but this also counts as an "explicit description".

From this, one can fill out the character table and find the characters of the three dimensional reps, but given that their dimension is small, I would hope there's a nice construction of them.

Comment: Matrices are here: http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/lin/L27/gap0/L27G1-Ar3aB0.g

Comment: Is there anything in the work of J A Green? As I recall it the characters of $\text{PSL}(2,q)$ are of degrees $1$ (1), $q$ (1), $q-1$ (lots), and $q+1$ (lots) - except that one of the $q\pm 1$ characters (it depends on whether $q=\pm 1 mod 4$) splits into two of half the degree. (I am assuming $q$ is odd, when $q$ is even there is no split.) So there must be an explanation of these two smaller degree representations which is independent of the characteristic.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'd be surprised if Sandy constructed these characters explcitly. First, these are not representations for $\mathrm{GL}_2$, but the special linear group, so would not appear in his '55 paper. Second, these are non-unipotent characters, and those were constructed using Jordan decompositions, leading only to the character, not the representation. I think his construction of the unipotent chracters is also not using representations, but Harish-Chandra induction, which yields characters only.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidA.Craven. I do remember a very long conversation with him (on a train to the BMC in Scotland) discussing the character tables of the PSLs: unfortunately I didn't take notes! But my main point is that there should be an explanation that doesn't depend on the fact $q=7$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician There's an explanation that the character splits upon restriction to the special linear group (just take its norm), but I don't even think there's a good description of the $(q-1)$-dimensional characters for $\mathrm{GL}_2$ in general, never mind the splitting of the particular one.

Comment: Is there a simpler construction of the six-dimensional rep that's the direct sum of these three-dimensional ones?

Comment: @AnginaSeng There is a $\mathbb{Z}$-form of that module. The matrices are here: http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/lin/L27/gap0/L27G1-Zr6aB0.g

Comment: There’s a construction in this paper by Noam Elkies on the Klein quartic but it’s not super satisfying to me: http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/elkies.pdf